# How to Append a value in map of firestore document using reactjs

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
  const manuallyRejected = async () => {
    if (ownManualStatus !== 'rejected') {
      updateDoc(doc(db, 'pairRequests', buddyData.uid), {
        manual: 'rejected',
        blocked: {
          [user.uid]: Date.now()
        }
      } , { merge: true });
      updateDoc(doc(db, 'pairRequests', user.uid), {
        blocked: {
          [buddyData.uid]: Date.now()
        }
      } ,{ merge: true });
    }
    setPairFound(false);
    setBuddyData(null);
  };
```

There is a map named blocked and it contains a field and value of useruid and timestamp of the users that are blocked. so what i am trying to do is add a new field but the updateDoc is overwriting all the previous fields. can anyone please tell me how i can do it . I tried using FieldPath but that was giving some error and i don't know if i was doing right or not. this was the code that was atleast working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`updateDoc` does **not** have a merge option as per the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_#parameters_72).

To update a field inside a `map` you can use the field path. This will add the new field or overwrite a field with the same name but it will **not** overwrite the other existing fields.

```
updateDoc(doc(db, 'pairRequests', buddyData.uid), {
   manual: 'rejected',
   'blocked.myNewField':'This is a new field'
  });
```